# Iframe in mobile devices - how automatically change height of the Iframe when the width of the window is changed in any devices

Tags: php, html, iframe, mobile, mobile-devices

I have A problem in my shortener website this is iframe

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?=$adurl?>"></iframe>
```

the websites in iframe appear on desktops good without problems but in mobile devices the iframe appear short from the bottom how make the websites appear full size in iframe automatically change size full in any devices

Thanks for the help advance

Comment: Use jquery to resize the height of that frame, based on window height - your bar height.

Answer (score 0):

Its kinda hard to read your question since you didn't use punctuation, but I think you need to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413475/how-to-resize-a-youtube-video-on-mobile-inside-of-a-div/35425613#35425613) SO question. 
And you need to close your `<div>` with `</div>`, but I think that that is just a copy/paste mistake.